# Difference between package-lock and node_modules/.package-lock

Tags: node.js, npm

What's the purpose of the additional `.package-lock.json` inside `node_modules`? It seems to be a subset of `package-lock.json`.

I assume this has been asked before, but i couldn't find anything in the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-locks), and google still refuses to properly search for punctuation symbols, so here we are.

PS: It's recreated by `npm i`, when i delete it. However i cannot find it on older projects of mine, so it appears to be a newer thing.

Comment: good question. I'd love to know too, so I filed https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2521

Comment: A comprehensive description for `node_modules/.package-lock.json`  can be found in the [Hidden Lockfiles](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/653769de359b8d24f0d17b8e7e426708f49cadb8/docs/content/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.md#hidden-lockfiles) section of the _"yet to be published docs"_ in the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The additional `node_modules/.package-lock.json` is a helper file, which speeds up npm under normal circumstances. When npm finds, that `node_modules` hasn't changed (checked by e.g. looking at the modified-time of package folders), it can be used instead of processing the folder repeatedly.

As RobC mentions in his comment:

> A comprehensive description for `node_modules/.package-lock.json` can be found in the [Hidden Lockfiles](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/653769de359b8d24f0d17b8e7e426708f49cadb8/docs/content/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.md#hidden-lockfiles) section of the "yet to be published docs" in the GitHub repo.

Comment: The documentation for Hidden Lockfiles has been published to [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#hidden-lockfiles).